# How do I update the tick values on my axis when zooming ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/q0ubpmwj/3/

It has an x and y axis and a rectangle which you can move and zoom into on screen using the mouse.

These axis are used as rulers, to measure whats shown on screen. I have found this example : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3892928

I want it similar but without the pan. So when i zoom in to my rectangle i want the tick values to scale according to the zoom. But Im unsure how to incorporate this in to my code.

I tried putting the code for the axis in a function and passing a scale through to it so id call it again in the redraw function but doesnt seem to be working correctly.

```
function updateAxis(scale){ //creates the axis

    x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width*scale]);

    y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, height*scale]);
.
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i solved it. I added this to the redraw.

```
 svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
```

Looks like i had what i needed there, just wasnt updating it at all :L

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/q0ubpmwj/4/